# python pandas conditional ranking

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
A1     1
A2     2
A3     1.5
B1     1
B2    -2
B3     2
B4    -1.5
```

Now I want a output of rank within each regex A*, B* etc.,

```
A1     1      3
A2     2      1
A3     1.5    2
B1     1      2
B2    -2      4
B3     2      1
B4    -1.5    3
```

How can I achieve this directly using pandas inbuilt functionalities as .rank gives only rank in entire set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` by `Series` created by [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
print (df)
    a    b
0  A1  1.0
1  A2  2.0
2  A3  1.5
3  B1  1.0
4  B2 -2.0
5  B3  2.0
6  B4 -1.5

a = df.a.str.extract('([a-zA-Z])', expand=False)
print (a)
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    B
5    B
6    B
Name: a, dtype: object

df['c'] = df.groupby(a).b.rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
print (df)
    a    b  c
0  A1  1.0  3
1  A2  2.0  1
2  A3  1.5  2
3  B1  1.0  2
4  B2 -2.0  4
5  B3  2.0  1
6  B4 -1.5  3
```